# Best way to validate international domain names in Go

Tags: go

What is the best way to validate international domain names in Go?

https://golang.org/pkg/net/?m=all#isDomainName

https://golang.org/src/net/dnsclient.go?s=3444:3476#L109

Maybe copying this function which isn't exported from net package?

We need to validate domains like icaan.org and example.(special characters)

EDIT: IDN https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Already using govalidator which fails to validate IDN's as it doesn't handle unicode characters https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator/blob/master/validator.go

Here are some examples of IDN's

- https://evertpot.com/internationalized-domain-names-are-you-ready/
- [http://مثال.إختبار](http://%D9%85%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84.%D8%A5%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1) - Arabic.
- [http://例子.测试](http://%E4%BE%8B%E5%AD%90.%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95) - Chinese (simplified)
- [http://例子.測試](http://%E4%BE%8B%E5%AD%90.%E6%B8%AC%E8%A9%A6) - Chinese (traditional)
- [http://παράδειγμα.δοκιμή](http://%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%AC%CE%B4%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B3%CE%BC%CE%B1.%CE%B4%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%B9%CE%BC%CE%AE) - greek
- [http://उद](http://%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%A6)ाहरण.परीक्षा Hindi
- [http://例え.テスト](http://%E4%BE%8B%E3%81%88.%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88) - Japanese
- [http://실례.테스트](http://%EC%8B%A4%EB%A1%80.%ED%85%8C%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8) - Korean
- [http://مثال.آزمایشی](http://%D9%85%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84.%D8%A2%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%DB%8C) - Persian
- [http://пример.испытание](http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80.%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - Russian

Just seen the reference to punycode.

Though all these punycode's are in the public suffix list https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

:(

Comment: What _exactly_ is "validate a international domain name" ?

Comment: Do you simply want to know if it is formatted correctly, or if it exists in the DNS?

Comment: Formatted correctly without illegal characters or just jargon.

Comment: IDN > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: You have to convert it to punycode for govalidator.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use the builtin functions [`url.Parse(string)`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) and [`url.Hostname()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Hostname) along with a regular expression to match sequences of Unicode letters/numbers/marks separated by dots (as represented in the sample data set).

For example:

```
var domainNamePattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^([\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_%+-]+\.)+[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+$`)

func main() {
  ss := []string{
    `https://evertpot.com/internationalized-domain-names-are-you-ready/`,
    `http://bogus!.com`,
    `https://foo1.bar2.com.gah.zip/`,
    `http://مثال.إختبار`,
    `http://例子.测试`,
    `http://例子.測試`,
    `http://παράδειγμα.δοκιμή`,
    `http://उदाहरण.परीक्षा`,
    `http://例え.テスト`,
    `http://실례.테스트`,
    `http://مثال.آزمایشی`,
    `http://пример.испытание`,
  }

  for _, s := range ss {
    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil || !domainNamePattern.MatchString(u.Hostname()) {
      bogusPart := s
      if err == nil {
        bogusPart = u.Hostname()
      }
      fmt.Printf("ERROR: invalid URL or hostname %q\n", bogusPart)
      continue
    }
    fmt.Printf("OK: hostname=%q\n", u.Hostname())
  }
}

// OK: hostname="evertpot.com"
// ERROR: invalid URL or hostname "bogus!.com"
// OK: hostname="foo1.bar2.com.gah.zip"
// OK: hostname="مثال.إختبار"
// OK: hostname="例子.测试"
// OK: hostname="例子.測試"
// OK: hostname="παράδειγμα.δοκιμή"
// OK: hostname="उदाहरण.परीक्षा"
// OK: hostname="例え.テスト"
// OK: hostname="실례.테스트"
// OK: hostname="مثال.آزمایشی"
// OK: hostname="пример.испытание"
```

Of course, more care should be taken to build the regular expression in such a way that it conforms to any relevant specifications, but this example should be a good starting point.